# Select data from data frame to multiply by array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, dataframe, filter

I have data in this type of format, there are hundreds of sources, and it currently all stored in one data frame structure like so:

> Source  --- Axis --- Constant --- Slope
>
> Green      Horizontal  2.1         3.4
>
> Green      Vertical    2.2         3.4
>
> Red        Horizontal  3.0         3.5
>
> Red        Vertical    2.0         3.6
>
> etc etc etc

What I am trying to do is generate set of matrices for each source that gives me the

total value = Horiz Const + Horiz Slope * x + Vert Const + Vert Slope * y

I have my sample x and y values in arrays.

Then I would like to be able to rank quickly work out the rank for each matrix at each position ie whats the lowest total value and then whats the delta of any given matrix at any given position to the lowest.

Apologies if this have been asked elsewhere I have looked but had no success

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: so far I end up splitting the data frame in two by once chopping out the vertical and multiplying by the y values and then chopping out the horizontal and multiplying by the x vales.
that kind of works but is really messy with lots of in between steps

Comment: I have also realised that my indexing is not unique / there was no proper indexing - perhaps someone could help with a multi-level index

actually where I say source above there are whole bunch of criteria and I am currently filtering them manually